# Can an external RFID/NFC reader detect the IPhone6?

Tags: iphone, nfc, iphone-6

Now that the IPhone6 has been available (in some markets at least), I would really like to know if someone has any information (or even tried) if the NFC chip inside the IPhone6 can be detected by an external reader? And in case it is possible, how much info can be read?

I know that there is currently no API access to NFC for IOS apps, so I would like to go a different route for now and simply identify an IPhone6 by holding it onto an external NFC reader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, the answer should be *yes*: iPhone 6 works in card emulation mode, so it must present itself to a reader *as a card*.

The readable info is not probably much, but at least you should be able to poll the existence of the payment app - sending SELECT APDUs (APDUs = commands to interact with smart cards such as the one being emulated by the iPhone) to known applications.

By sending an empty SELECT or a SELECT targeting the Issuer Security Domain (a management application which AID is usually `A000000151000000` or `A000000003000000`) the card should answer with a data structure with information about the card or the chip.

Now I just need to get my hands on one and test it...

Comment: thanks for that! I will be able to get hold of an IPhone6 for testing sometime in October. Any suggestions which NFC reader should work (best) for that?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to use an Android phone with NFC capabilities - since the iPhone is operating in card emulation mode, the Android phone working in reader mode should get you the info I mention, and more. I've found he apps TagInfo (by NXP, the manufacturer of the iPhone 6's NFC chip) and NFC TagInfo quite useful when meeting new cards.

Comment: As of October 9th, 2014, the IPhone6 is not detected by an external NFC reader at all (on both IOS 8.0.2 and 8.1b2). So I guess this NFC inside the IPhone6 will need to be activated by either another IOS update or some other app/setting. Will update when new info emerges.

Comment: IOS 8.1 release apparently enables NFC -- but only after adding a supported US credit card (which I don't have). So I'm hoping someone else can provide some more details about the capabilities included in the NFC implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* read the UUID, however it is randomized each time, making it useless for identifying the device.

See https://youtu.be/LmjpO4evkw0 and http://flomio.com/2014/10/apple-pay-makes-nfc-relevant/ for further information